# Can I schedule updates for a specific time of day?

Tags: updates, internet, schedule

Satellite based internet is my only option.  My ISP is not reliable and I must schedule downloads (ex. updates, video) to off-peak hours.

I am very new to Ubuntu.  My ISP does not throttle my speed between 3am and 6am EDT when I am asleep, so I would like to schedule updates for this time.

Are there any methods to schedule updates to download only at a specific time of day?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use cron-apt to download and install updates between midnight and 5am?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193823/how-can-i-use-cron-apt-to-download-and-install-updates-between-midnight-and-5am): an older answer, but process should be the same

Comment: This may seem off topic, but have you checked to see if there is point-to-point wireless where you are?  Take a look at http://www.wispa.org/Directories/Find-a-WISP

Comment: You may also look into `unattended upgrades`. It gives you more control over what types of upgrades are done unattended, but it is harder to setup.